# Execute JQuery function for 1 div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a few controls which edits the background color, font etc  of the specific page loaded into the application.

[image]

Now when I change for example, the background-color, the whole page gets that color.

Of course, I don't want my control panel (left and right) to change as well.

the whole page is built as an html table, and within the middle column, is a div which is the page I would like to edit.

middle div code:

```
<td style = " vertical-align:top" ><% if (Model != null && Model.PublicationID != 0)
       {
           Html.RenderPartial("TopBar", Model); %>
    <div class="xcontainer">

        <% foreach (QuartzNew.Models.Edition e in Model.Editions)
           {
               if (e != null)
               {
                   Model.SelectedEdition = e;
                   Html.RenderPartial("GridCell", Model); // If SingleIssueShopLayout="Grid" else Html.RenderPartial("SearchResult", Model);
               }
           }
        %>
        <% } %>
    </div>
    </td>
```

Jquery function I would like to execute:

```
               $('#page-properties-BGcolor-Colorpicker').miniColors({
                   change: function (hex) {
                       $('#page-properties-BGcolor-Colorpicker').val(hex)
                       $("html, body").not($(".Controlpanel")).css("background", hex);
                       //                    fillPageValues()
                   }
               });
```

Comment: Can't you poit directly to the middle element? Can you show an example on jsfiddle? You must use table for formatting, can be difficult to style

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply changing:

`$("html, body").not($(".Controlpanel")).css("background", hex);`

To

`$(".xcontainer").css("background", hex);`

At present the scope of your argument is potentially not specific enough to simply isolate the element you wish to target.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector retrieves the `html` and `body` elements which are not `$(".Controlpanel")` which is a bit nonsensical, because that's always the case and will change the background of both html and body.

You have to select the element you want to change, not the html an body. Try this:

```
$('.xcontainer').css("background", hex);
```